# Multiple STOMP subscriptions from JS to Spring in one request

Tags: javascript, java, spring, stomp, sockjs

The goal is to make multy-room chat using web interface and Spring framework. Lookes like [STOMP](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket) over [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) is the best combo for such project. STOMP's destination based subscription resolves all broadcasting issues. But if user uses 100 (for example) chats at once I need to send 100 subscription requests from web client each time he logs in.

So I'm looking for alternative one-request solution. Let me to consolidate questions:

1) Is there a way to make one client-side STOMP request for several subscriptions at once? If it is possible to make such request using other JS library - then I'll be glad to try it.

2) Is there a way to initiate subscriptions from Spring backend side? It would be great to register several destination message queries for one client on server side - I can use special request for that or do that during logging in.

3) Any other suggestions about this issue? Again: I'm glad to try other trendy tech as a last resort.

The code beloiw is the most simple echo service. I'm just testing this protocol and technology.

Basic client code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.s = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/portfolio");
    window.s.onopen = function () {
        window.stompClient = Stomp.over(window.s);

        stompClient.connect('admin', 'admin', function(frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ', frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/echo', function(messageOutput) {
                console.log(messageOutput.body);
            })}, function(e){console.log("Fail My: ", e);})();
    };
};
```

STOMP config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
        .setClientLibraryUrl( "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.3.0/dist/sockjs.min.js" );
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

STOMP controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/greetings")
    @SendTo("/topic/echo")
    public String handleMessage(@Payload String greeting) {
        System.out.println("[received]:" + greeting);
        return "[echo]: " + greeting;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The STOMP specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SUBSCRIBE) indicates that 1 `SUBSCRIBE` frame correlates to 1 subscription. In other words, there's no way to get multiple subscriptions for a single `SUBSCRIBE` frame.

It's possible (although unlikely in my opinion) that a library/API would wrap the ability to send multiple `SUBSCRIBE` frames in a single call, but that would just a convenience method and wouldn't actually yield any kind of performance benefit at the protocol level.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions about Java-side SUBSCRIBE initiation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "SUBSCRIBE initiation." Did my answer address your question?

Comment: Yes, the answer resolved my question. I can't do (+1) to your answer because my reputation is too low for now.